# WooCommerce: How to edit the get_price_html

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to edit the price value for a single product.

In `single-product/price.php` there is a template call to `$product->get_price_html`. How can I edit that function/method to change the way the HTML is presented?

At the moment even if I delete all the contents of the function located in `class-wc-product` it still miraculously displays? Anyone know why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Core and plugin files should never be edited directly, as any updates could overwrite your changes. If you look in WooCommerce source at the `get_price_html` method, there are a number of [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) available to modify the output of the function.

See [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) in Codex for more info on adding filters to [`apply_filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) calls.

From `get_price_html` in `class-wc-product`:

```
return apply_filters('woocommerce_get_price_html', $price, $this);
```

So to add your own filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wpa83367_price_html', 100, 2 );
function wpa83367_price_html( $price, $product ){
    return 'Was:' . str_replace( '<ins>', ' Now:<ins>', $price );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way why when I delete the contents of the main function it still returns the output as normal

Comment: So lets say if there was a sale on and it returns me `<del>£2</del><ins>£1</ins>`, how can i change that into `Was:<del>£2</del> Now:<ins>£1</ins>` with a filter?

Comment: not sure, not too familiar with WooCommerce, perhaps another class extends it. see edit above for your second question.

Comment: Brill, ;), great help

Comment: I am trying to know that what happening in default `woocommerce_get_price_html` filter for `$price`. In my site,woocommerce shows 0$ for free products instead `Free!`

Comment: Which file has that function? I can't find the file. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
function wpa83368_price_html( $price,$product ){
   // return $product->price;
    if ( $product->price > 0 ) {
      if ( $product->price && isset( $product->regular_price ) ) {
        $from = $product->regular_price;
        $to = $product->price;
        return '<div class="old-colt"><del>'. ( ( is_numeric( $from ) ) ? woocommerce_price( $from ) : $from ) .' Retail </del>  | </div><div class="live-colst">'.( ( is_numeric( $to ) ) ? woocommerce_price( $to ) : $to ) .'Our Price</div>';
      } else {
        $to = $product->price;
        return '<div class="live-colst">' . ( ( is_numeric( $to ) ) ? woocommerce_price( $to ) : $to ) . 'Our Price</div>';
      }
   } else {
     return '<div class="live-colst">0 Our Price</div>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Even if your code can work (and I have no reason to think it doesn't) this is a Q/A site, not a code repository so it's better share expertice and knowledge explaining your code, instead of just write code with no explaination nor inline comments...

Comment: the code also uses object properties which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

in the **functions.php**

```
function h08831n_get_price($product){
        $price_html = '<div class="product-price">';
        if ( $product->get_price() > 0 ) {
            if ($product->get_price() && $product->get_regular_price()) {
                $from = $product->get_regular_price();
                $to = $product->get_price();
                $price_html .= '<del>'. ( ( is_numeric( $from ) ) ? wc_price( $from ) : $from ) .'</del><ins>'.( ( is_numeric( $to ) ) ? wc_price( $to ) : $to ) .'</ins>';
            }else{
                $to = $product->get_price();
                $price_html .= '<ins>' . ( ( is_numeric( $to ) ) ? wc_price( $to ) : $to ) . '</ins>';
            }
        }else{
            $price_html .= '<div class="free">free</div>';
        }
        $price_html .= '</div>';
        return $price_html;
    }
```

in the where you want to display the price like **single-product.php**

```
global $product;
echo h08831n_get_price($product);
```

you can also remove **wc_price** in the function to remove woocommerce default HTML formats