# How to overwrite price html in woocommerce single product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to overwrite price html in single product page in woocommerce. I have used the below code but its displaying twice.

When click on plus or minus in product details page , the price should be changed

```
<?php
```

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 11);
//add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 99,2 );

```
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    // let's setup our divs
    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>',__('Product Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    //echo sprintf('<div id="cart_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>',__('Cart Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    current_cart_total = <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total; ?>,
                    currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                        var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value),
                        cart_total = parseFloat(product_total + current_cart_total);

                        $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        $('#cart_total_price .price').html( currency + cart_total.toFixed(2));
                    }
                    $('#product_total_price,#cart_total_price').toggle(!(this.value <= 1));

                });
            });

        </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I think that this was answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83367/woocommerce-how-to-edit-the-get-price-html).