# Add suffix to price html does not work

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks

I am trying to add a suffix through a filter hook to a product price in Wooommerce, but for some strange reason the `woocommerce_get_price_html` filter hook (like explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83367/woocommerce-how-to-edit-the-get-price-html)) does not change anything to the price.

What can be the obstacle for not adding the suffix? Or do I need to use another hook?

**My filter hook:**

```
function pr_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
   return $price . ' test';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'pr_price_suffix' );
```

**The code that prints the price in single-product.php:**

```
<?php echo wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the filter will work in your template, since you're using `wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) )` .. a possible workaround:

```
function pr_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
 return wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) ). ' test';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'pr_price_suffix', 10, 2  );
```

and in your single-product.php template:

```
 <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
```